# Changing Leaflet ImageLayer With File Input

Tags: leaflet

I'm working on a dynamic image mapper that will users can load their floor plan of apartment then put markers on parts of floor. So I wan't to change url of image layer of Leaflet map dynamically.

I'm loading map with ChangeMap function for the first time. It loads my image correctly.

```
function ChangeMap(_url)
{
var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 5,
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([50.4333, 30.5167], 3);

// dimensions of the image
var w = 1526,
    h = 626,
    url = _url;

// calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

// add the image overlay,
// so that it covers the entire map
var overlay = L.imageOverlay(url, bounds);
overlay.addTo(map);
}
```

But if I try another time without refresh the page I'm getting an error "map container is alreay initialized". After that error I thought I can add div with id='map' dynamically like this.

```
var mapContainer = $("#mapContainer");
mapContainer.append("<div id='map' width='100%' height='400px'></div>");
```

I added that append function at the beginning of my ChangeMap() function. But this time there was no map on page. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only initialize the map once...So take `var map = L.map('map', {...` out of `ChangeMap` and only run it once before.I'd also recommend only initializing the L.imageOverlay once...and using [`setUrl`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay-seturl) to dynamically swap when needed inside `ChangeMap`.